# Forge returning error when ran on ubuntu w/ java 17

Tags: java, ubuntu, minecraft-forge

Today i tried to install forge on Ubuntu 20.10 with the command `java -jar forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.2318-1.8.9-universal.jar` previously i have ran `sudo apt update` so most of my packages utd well here is the error

```java
We appear to be missing one or more essential library files.
You will need to add them to your server before FML and Forge will run successfully.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:25)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:12)
```

could some one tell me what the problem is i want to use some mods